# ¿Cómo puedo obtener el valor de una sola propiedad en C# usando Newtonsoft?

Tags: c#, webservice

De un webservice recibo un json:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
        "errors": [{
                "message": "EMAIL_EXISTS",
                "domain": "global",
                "reason": "invalid"
            }
        ],
    }
}
```

Es almacenado en un `string`, lo que quiero hacer es solo obtener el valor de la propiedad `message`, ¿cómo puedo hacer eso?

Comment: ¿Qué has intentado/investigado?

Comment: 2 opciones, parsear el resultado para trabajar solo con la parte de message o en el web service solo enviar la parte de message

Comment: muchas gracias a todos por sus repuestas, en realidad quería saber si podía obtener directamente el valor de la propiedad sin tener que pasear el string para evitar el consumo de recursos que supone esta operación, se me olvido mencionar que estoy consumiendo el webservice de un tercero por lo tanto no lo puedo modificar.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Se puede hacer *parse* del string que obtienes para convertirlo a `JObject`, de la siguiente forma:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string str = "{\"error\": " +
            "{\"code\": 400,\"message\": \"EMAIL_EXISTS\"," +
            "\"errors\": [{\"message\": \"EMAIL_EXISTS\"," +
            "\"domain\": \"global\",\"reason\": \"invalid\"}],}}";

        // Se hace parse al string de origen.
        var json = JObject.Parse(str);

        // El valor de la propiedad 'message'.
        var message = (string)json["error"]["message"];
    }
}
```

También se puede realizar utilizando la funcionalidad dinámica de C#, así:

```
string str = "{ ...";

// El objeto JSON se carga de forma dinámica y es evaluado en tiempo de ejecución.
dynamic json = JObject.Parse(str);
string message = json.error.message;
```

Comment: Gracias, quería evitar hacer el  parse, sin embargo creo que es mejor hacer esta operación de la forma que me indicas.